# Copy & Paste, 2011 Edition

Tags: javascript

How can I copy and paste text using JavaScript?

Most of the methods I've found via Google don't seem to work with newer browsers/versions of Flash. Are there any methods that still work?

Comment: Using ZeroClipboard.js (& flash) is the only method left, and might dissappear one of these days. only older versions of ie allows copy using javascript. but then again users can copy things them self. The 2011 edition is called `CTRL+C`

Comment: Just tried running the example that came with ZeroClipboard. Does not work on Ubuntu/Chrome.

Comment: I sure as hell hope Javascript doesn't have clipboard access or ever will, at least not without having to ask for permission. I don't need having to worry whether every webpage I visit is sniffing for clipboard data.

Comment: @Mark actually it works on Ubuntu 11.10 , Chrome 15. ZeroClipboard 1.0.7, it's not very simple to implement

Comment: @Ibu: http://bowser.effectgames.com/~jhuckaby/zeroclipboard/ Hrm...works for me at home (Windows 7/FF7). Running 9.04 at work I think. Or 9.10? One or the other.

Comment: @Inerdia: Good point...I was using it for legitimate purposes though. Having to accept clipboard access would be fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

For webkit browsers only, in the Safari developer library, they have this [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/CopyAndPaste.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001234-BAJGJJAH) for "Using the Pasteboard From JavaScript".